# Should I use a session for a non authenticated user?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a requirement, have non authenticated users fill out a form that includes a back end generated captcha in order to submit approvals, I'm using Spring MVC and Cage to generate the captcha

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
public class ContactController {

    @RequestMapping("/contact")
    public String contact(Map<String, Object> model, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.info("In contact");
        try {
            final String captchaCode = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5);
            generate(new GCage(), 10, "cg1", ".jpg", captchaCode);
            final File file = Paths.get("./cg13.jpg").toFile();
            FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
            String base64String = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes), "UTF-8");;
            model.put("image", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String);
            model.put("captcha", captchaCode);
            session.setAttribute("captcha", captchaCode);
        } catch (IOException  e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return "contact";
    }

    @PostMapping("/check")
    public String checkCaptcha(final Map<String, Object> model, HttpSession session) {
        log.info("in check captcha");
        final String captcha = (String) session.getAttribute("captcha");
        return "contact";
    }
```

In Thymeleaf I'm using

```
<img th:src="@{${image}}" />

<form th:action="@{/check}" th:object="${captcha}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

is it a bad practice to create a session for a non authenticated user like this? How else can this be handled then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine, but beware of [session fixation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation). Spring's session handling is generally pretty good. Its default configuration will cause a [change of session ID](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/ns-config.html#ns-session-fixation) for when the user eventually authenticates.

Comment: How can you distinguish between an authenticated user a non authenticated user in that case if both have an HttpSession object? say for a shopping cart

Comment: Spring maintains a `SecurityContext` in the session to keep track of authentication state. Some docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/technical-overview.html#securitycontextholder-securitycontext-and-authentication-objects).